# windows phone App is not starting after changing the namespace

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am developing an app that was working fine till 2 days back. But when today I started it again its not starting. When I launch It, it exits as soon as it is started. I have changed nothing in my code since last launch still. I see no pointer about it. Neither any exception nor anything else.
My recent changes include change in app icon & package name. But I had run the app after these changes. don't know whats wrong?

this is only thing I can provide:

```
> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: DefaultDomain):
> Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\mscorlib.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
> Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
> AppDomain): Loaded
> 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ni.dll'. Skipped
> loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
> Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
> Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
> 'C:\windows\system32\System.Windows.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
> Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
> AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.Net.ni.dll'. Skipped
> loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My
> Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll:
> Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded 'C:\windows\system32\System.ni.dll'.
> Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option
> 'Just My Code' is enabled. 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR
> C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight AppDomain): Loaded
> 'C:\windows\system32\System.Xml.ni.dll'. Skipped loading symbols.
> Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
> 'TaskHost.exe' (CLR C:\windows\system32\coreclr.dll: Silverlight
> AppDomain): Loaded
> 'C:\Data\Programs\{F397F82A-71C2-4C23-A644-242430FC6247}\Install\NFL.DLL'.
> Symbols loaded. The program '[3252] TaskHost.exe' has exited with code
> 0 (0x0).
```

Comment: Could you put a try catch block and debug and see where you are getting the exception? This error message is not descriptive enough to come to any conclusion.

Comment: @Bharath I said I didn't have any clue, I tried it in debug mode but that also didn't help. but well I found the reason & solution now.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

found the solution, the reason was the change I made in namespace:

After changing the namespace, you should update the startup object as well. Go to `Project>Properties` then under `startup object` select the object that includes the updated `namespace.App` object.

Comment: The startup object is under the 'application' tab, which you may not default landing on project properties.  Also, it is a drop-down which is rather suprising.

Comment: I know it's an old thread, but I need to thank you. I lost so much time on this... the 'startup object' property did the trick.